# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined in ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic4

This is the error message:
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

HTML

```html
<ion-searchbar (ionChange)=search($event) color='medium'></ion-searchbar>
```

ts

```js
    allMessages: message[];
    messages : message[];


  search(event) {
  const text = event.target.value;
  if (text && text.trim() !== '') {
    this.room.messages = this.allMessages.filter(
      message => message.content.toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase()));
  } else {
    // Blank text, clear the search, show all products
    this.room.messages = this.allMessages;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array `this.allMessages` has to be filled before filtering over it. It seems to be like it has no value in it. You have defined the variable but haven't declared it. You have to declare it like

```
allMessages: message[] = [];
```

Comment: are you removing values from it or redeclaring it somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to initialize correctly your variables then check that the event is not triggering when template initialization has already finished there was a issues some times ago about that.

If all is correct a quick fix could be doing the following:

```
this.room.messages = this.allMessages && this.allMessages.filter(...someCode) || []
```

Also you can check the first statement with **isNullOrUndefined() method or a ternary conditional**